# Intel Pentium D 830. CPU usage 0%

Tags: windows-xp, cpu, freeze

Specifications: 
Processor: Intel Pentium D 830 (64 bit)
OS: Windows XP Media Center Edition 32-bit
Graphics: Nvidia 9600GT
Ram: 4 Gigabytes Physical, 2 Gigabytes used by windows

Problem: 
After finally fixing the rest of the problems with the system, which all involved memory and a couple bad ram-modules which are all gone now. I have gotten Windows XP 32 bit (which came with the computer) working. I will be replacing the OS when I feel confident that the computer is working, because I will need to buy win7 64.

After running for a while doing something mildly-intensive the computer halts completely and nothing works, except maybe the mouse and anything on the screen that updates without using advanced graphics (it seems, I need to verify if it is only "simple" graphics or all graphics that work, "simple" seeming to be non-3d) I was lucky enough to have task manager working at one of the complete freezes and it displays 0 CPU usage. This number does not change no matter how long I wait, although the task manager continues to update it's information. During some to most crashes the mouse does not function either.

I will gladly supply any other information that may be required.

On a side note: it is completely possible that after it's many years of service, the motherboard could be done for. Of it's original parts all of it's ram and it's hard-disk have died.

Edit:
I have done some diagnostics.

1. Everything on the board LOOKS in perfect shape
2. The processor has been inspected from under its huge heatsink to check if it has "melted" as, apparently, the 830 had problems with overheating to the point that they physically damage the chip.
3. all drivers in windows have been verified and updated
4. All cards have been verified to be correctly seated and working

i still have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: The computer can't be *completely halted* if the Task Manager still works.

Comment: Check the motherboard for swollen/leaking capacitors, this was a real problem during the D830 years...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague

Comment: Also check for a loose or broken CPU heatsink retainer.

Comment: so. i've checked every capacitor, and each one looks completely fine. the cpu cooling system looks fine, i've verified all fans work when the system is powered on.

Comment: ok, so I've tried installing some possible driver updates. and then i reboot and stress tested it. it has not crashed *so far* although while trying to play minecraft it ground to a halt as soon as i opened a world and continued getting about 20 seconds per frame. the computer then ground to a halt as before but after some alt-tabbing allowed me to get to the task manager and the system started working again. i am unsure if this is related.

Comment: it has crashed after about an hour. minecraft didn't succeed but the system randomly locked up like usual, and then continued to a complete halt. no mouse or screen updates. BIOS did not record a problem. nothing is reported in the event viewer for system. under application there are a couple Userev warnings about the registry being in use during a log-off. and 2 MPSampleSubmission entries that contain a bunch of data that i could copy and paste later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the CPU has been overheating?

You may be able to enter your BIOS and view logs to see if that's been happening?

Comment: i have reviewed the bios log and the last message in the log is the one telling me the amount of ram has changed.